# SASS\SCSS: селекторы разделенные запятой

Tags: css, sass, scss

Есть подобный код на `CSS`

```
#content .page_header_wrap header>h1.entry-title, .woocommerce .entry-header h1.entry-title {
    font-family: LatoWebThin;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

Столкнулся с тем что не могу понять как правильно в `SASS`\ `SCSS` обработать разделение запятой?

```
$font_family_1: LatoWebThin;

#content {
    .page_header_wrap {
        header {
            >h1.entry-title {
                font-family: $font_family_1;
                font-size: 50px;
            }
        }
    }
}
.woocommerce {
    .entry-header {
        h1.entry-title {
            font-family: $font_family_1;
            font-size: 50px;
        }
    }
}
```

Кода получается в два раза больше. Как данная задача правильно решается в `SASS`\ `SCSS` ?

Comment: можно использовать mixin и циклы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы должны использовать плейсхолдеры

```
%awesome {
      font-family: $font_family_1;
      font-size: 50px;
}

#content .page_header_wrap header>h1.entry-title {
    @extend %awesome;
}
.woocommerce .entry-header h1.entry-title {
    @extend %awesome;
}
```

P.S. иерархию сделаете, если нужно...

Comment: Хм... подоход с классами мне знаком, но кода все равно больше чем CSS( Я надеялся что это решается все таки каким нибудь оператором

Comment: после преобразования в CSS, кода будет не больше, поскольку `@extend` преобразуется к записи через запятую

Comment: @user199588 То что я написал, на выходе 1 в 1 ваш css. Но SASS вам даёт дополнительные удобства - вы плэйсхолдер можете создать в базовом файле, а использовать его в других файлах... потом внеся изменения в плэйсхолдере, оно автоматом измениться  в нужных местах в готовом css